# Why is Process.getInputStream omitting spaces? [Java 20]

Tags: java, process, inputstream, processbuilder

I'm getting the `InputStream` from a process and printing it like this:

```java
String line = null;
var iStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((line = iStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(line);
}
```

The issue is that when I print `line`, it's spaces are omitted, e.g., if I execute `ls` in the child process, it prints all directory contents concatenated, like this:

```bash
dir1dir2file1file2
```

What the hell is happening here?

---

Obs.: it works fine when I call `inheritIO` when instantiating the `ProcessBuilder`, but I have reasons not to use this method.

Comment: It is not 'omitting spaces'. `readLine()` removes the line terminator, and you aren't printing one yourself. Use `println()`. This is all documented.

Comment: But  when I execute `ls`, it outputs all contents in the same line, not with line terminators in between

Comment: try to execute `ls > sample` and check the format inside `sample`; or `ls | more`  (terminal output is formatted differently) ... searching a bit more, from `info ls`: "*... If standard output is a terminal, the
output is in columns (sorted vertically) and control characters are output as question marks; otherwise, the output is listed one per line and control characters are output as-is. ...*"

Comment: use `ls -C` if you need the output in columns. Anyway you will probably still *want* to use `println` instead of `print`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you're using the `print` method.

To place a new-line delimiter after the value, use the `println` method.

Here is an example using *[print](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String))*.

```java
System.out.print("a");
System.out.print("b");
System.out.print("c");
```

Output

```
abc
```

And here is an example using *[println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String))*.

```java
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("b");
System.out.println("c");
```

Output

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: But why is each character in a different line? If when I execute `ls`, it outputs all contents in the same line?

Comment: @GabrielBergoc, I see what you're saying, interesting.  I recommend starting a debugging process; set a breakpoint on the `while` statement and view the contents _iStream_.  Possibly, it is returning the components with _\r_ delimiters?  I'm not sure.